# Raspberry Pi 2 Libbcm2835 exception with library RaspberryPiDotNet

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, monodevelop, raspberry-pi2

I'm new with the Raspberry pi.

I'm working with monodevelop, and after I imported the library `RaspberryPiDotNew` to control GPIO -

I ran a simple script and got an exception:

```
using System;
using RaspberryPiDotNet;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GPIOMem led = new GPIOMem(GPIOPins.V2_GPIO_12)
            while(true)
            {
                led.Write(PinState.High);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                led.Write(PinState.Low);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error `System.TypeInitializationException has been thrown`

```
System.TypeInitializationException : An exception was thrown by the type initializer for RassberryPiDotNet.GPIOMem --->System.Exception:libbcm2835.so 
at (wrapper managed-to-native)RaspberryPiDontNet.GPIOMem:bcm2835_init()
at RaspberryPiDotNet.GPIOMem..cctor()[0x00001]in
```

Comment: are you executing this as root? libbcm needs elevated privileges to run

Comment: so what should i do in this case ?

Comment: run it as root or sudo it

Comment: How to do this ? i mean the command ,im sorry but i never used linux

Comment: sudo mono yourexe.exe